# how to change the orientation of the tkinter canvas

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

By default the canvas seems to go right and down, meaning that coordinate `(0,0)` is in the top left corner and coordinate `(1,1)` goes one right and one down. I was wondering if there is a way to change the orientation so that the origin is maybe bottom left and `(1,1)` would be one right and one up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canvas uses a 4 quadrant Cartesian coordinate (0,0 = top/left)
When defining `canvas = tk.Canvas(...` try using `scrollregion = "-200 -200 200 200"`
Try setting `canvas.yview_scroll(0, "units")` and `canvas.xview_scroll(0, "units")`

Here is a small demo.

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.LabelFrame(master, text = "Coords Here", relief = tk.FLAT)
frame.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

canvas = tk.Canvas(
    frame, 
    highlightthickness = 0, background = "black",
    width = 400, height = 400, takefocus = 1,
    scrollregion = "-200 -200 200 200")
canvas.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

#canvas.yview_scroll(0, "units")
#canvas.xview_scroll(0, "units")

def rowcol(event):
    frame["text"] = f"{canvas.canvasx(event.x)} | {canvas.canvasy(event.y)}"

canvas.bind("<Motion>", rowcol)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer does not address OP question.

Comment: My example puts 0,0 at the center of the canvas, it doesn't take much to effort to have 0,0 at bottom right of canvas, `scrollregion(-n, -n, 0, 0)` would do it.

Comment: But OP wants the coordinates go right and up, that is reverse y-axis.

Comment: Right and up puts 0,0 at bottom left, that's Quadrant 1, positive x and negative y `scrollregion = "0 -400 400 0")` in my example.