# How to show only a portion of the tkinter canvas by cropping the tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I want to be able to zoom into my tkinter canvas. My tkinter canvas is 500x500px, and I only want my window to display the center 200x200px portion of this canvas. How do I do this? I know that I can just specify my window size as 200x200px using root.geometry("200x200+0+0"), but this causes my window to display the top left corner of my canvas, and not the center. Before I do anything, my entire canvas looks like this:

[image: entire canvas]

Ultimately, I want my window to look like this, with the canvas centered within the window:

[image: desired final result]

This is my code:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("")
root.geometry("200x200+0+0")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = root, width = 500, height = 500)

canvas.create_oval(200, 200, 300, 300, outline = "black", fill = "blue")
canvas.pack()
```

which returns:

[image: my problem]

As you can see, the canvas is not centered, and the window is showing the upper left hand corner at the moment. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried to do on your own to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried to use `canvas.create_window()` and tkinter frames but I haven't been able to get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596816/how-to-change-the-orientation-of-the-tkinter-canvas), I found out there is an option when creating a tkinter canvas called `scrollregion`. The format of the argument is `"x0 y0 x1 y1"` for anyone that is wondering, where *(x0, y0)* is the upper-left corner of the area of the canvas I want to show and *(x1, y1)* is the bottom-right corner of the same area. My code should be fixed to this:

```py
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = root, width = 500, height = 500, scrollregion = "150 150 350 350")
```

Be wary that these coordinates do not account for a scrollbar...I'm still working on figuring that out. Much thanks to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804207/tkinter-put-scrollbar-on-canvas-at-bottom-position) as well, specifically the following words:

> I don't see any difference between putting the y-scrollbar to the bottom or putting the canvas view to the bottom because the two are linked.